# I have a Table View and five data sources

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view. There are five data sources. When I click on the button when the data source switch, but click the first button will be empty, the other button click normal, has not found the reason.

This is the code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>

@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray * dataArr;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray * dataArr0;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray * dataArr1;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray * dataArr2;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray * dataArr3;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray * dataArr4;

@property(nonatomic,strong)UITableView * mainTab;

@end


static NSString * cellID = @"cellID";

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableArray * mutarr0 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"all",@"all",@"all",@"all",@"all", nil];
    self.dataArr0 = mutarr0;

    NSMutableArray * mutarr1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Waiting",@"Waiting",@"Waiting",@"Waiting",@"Waiting",@"Waiting", nil];
    self.dataArr1 = mutarr1;

    NSMutableArray * mutarr2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"processing",@"processing",@"processing",@"processing", nil];
    self.dataArr2 = mutarr2;

    NSMutableArray * mutarr3 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"End",@"End",@"End",@"End",@"End",@"End",@"End", nil];
    self.dataArr3 = mutarr3;

    NSMutableArray * mutarr4 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"cancel",@"cancel",@"cancel",@"cancel",@"cancel", nil];
    self.dataArr4 = mutarr4;

    self.dataArr = mutarr0;

    NSArray * segArr = @[@"all",@"Waiting",@"processing",@"End",@"cancel"];

    UISegmentedControl * segC = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:segArr];

    segC.frame = CGRectMake(0,64, self.view.frame.size.width,50);

    [segC addTarget:self action:@selector(change:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    UITableView * tabVC = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetMaxY(segC.frame),self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 50) style: UITableViewStylePlain];

    tabVC.delegate = self;
    tabVC.dataSource = self;
    self.mainTab = tabVC;

    [tabVC registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:cellID];

    [self.view addSubview:segC];
    [self.view addSubview:tabVC];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return self.dataArr.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = self.dataArr[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

-(void)change:(UISegmentedControl *)sender{
    if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        [self.dataArr removeAllObjects];
        [self.dataArr addObjectsFromArray:self.dataArr0];

        NSLog(@"%lu33333333333333",self.dataArr.count);
        //        NSLog(@"%lu44444444444444",self.dataArr0.count);
        //        //NSLog(@"%@-------%@",self.dataArr0[0],self.dataArr0[1]);
        [self.mainTab reloadData];
    }else if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){
        [self.dataArr removeAllObjects];
        [self.dataArr addObjectsFromArray:self.dataArr1];

        NSLog(@"2");
        [self.mainTab reloadData];
    }else if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 2){
        //
        [self.dataArr removeAllObjects];
        [self.dataArr addObjectsFromArray:self.dataArr2];

        [self.mainTab reloadData];
        NSLog(@"3");
    }else if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 3){
        [self.dataArr removeAllObjects];
        [self.dataArr addObjectsFromArray:self.dataArr3];

        [self.mainTab reloadData];
        //        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        NSLog(@"4");
    }else if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 4){
        [self.dataArr removeAllObjects];
        [self.dataArr addObjectsFromArray:self.dataArr4];

        [self.mainTab reloadData];
        //        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        NSLog(@"5");
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary problem is that in `viewDidLoad` you do:

```
self.dataArr = mutarr0;
```

And then in your `change:` method you do:

```
[self.dataArr removeAllObjects];
```

This erases all of the values from `mutarr0` (which is also `self.dataArr0`).

The best way to fix this is to change all lines of the form:

```
[self.dataArr removeAllObjects];
[self.dataArr addObjectsFromArray:self.dataArr4];
```

to:

```
self.dataArr = self.dataArr4;
```

That's it. No need to remove or add any objects.

With that working, there are other big improvements you can make. Mainly, get rid of all of the array properties. You don't need 5 separate array properties. Just create one that represents an array of your arrays.

Now your code can be simplified to just:

```
@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *current;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSArray *data;

@property(nonatomic,strong)UITableView * mainTab;

@end


static NSString * cellID = @"cellID";

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableArray *mutarr0 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"all",@"all",@"all",@"all",@"all", nil];
    NSMutableArray *mutarr1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Waiting",@"Waiting",@"Waiting",@"Waiting",@"Waiting",@"Waiting", nil];
    NSMutableArray *mutarr2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"processing",@"processing",@"processing",@"processing", nil];
    NSMutableArray *mutarr3 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"End",@"End",@"End",@"End",@"End",@"End",@"End", nil];
    NSMutableArray *mutarr4 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"cancel",@"cancel",@"cancel",@"cancel",@"cancel", nil];

    self.data = @[ mutarr0, mutarr1, mutarr2, mutarr3, mutarr4 ];
    self.current = self.data[0];

    NSArray * egArr = @[ @"all", @"Waiting", @"processing", @"End", @"cancel" ];

    UISegmentedControl * segC = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:segArr];

    segC.frame = CGRectMake(0,64, self.view.frame.size.width,50);

    [segC addTarget:self action:@selector(change:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    UITableView * tabVC = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetMaxY(segC.frame),self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 50) style: UITableViewStylePlain];

    tabVC.delegate = self;
    tabVC.dataSource = self;
    self.mainTab = tabVC;

    [tabVC registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:cellID];

    [self.view addSubview:segC];
    [self.view addSubview:tabVC];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return self.current.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = self.current[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

-(void)change:(UISegmentedControl *)sender{
    if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex != UISegmentedControlNoSegment {
        self.current = self.data[sender.selectedSegmentIndex];
        [self.mainTab reloadData];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Your method has solved my problem and thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change your code structure, though I agree it could be written more efficiently. But the main problem is in this line:

```
self.dataArr = mutarr0;
```

You self.dataArr was NEVER initialized as an independent property. Just replace that line with these and it should work:

```
self.dataArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // initialize it first!
[self.dataArr addObjectsFromArray:mutarr0]; // and then use it
```

You should also initialize all the other properties,
dataArr0-dataArr5.

Comment: Actually, the line `self.dataArr = mutarr0;` does initialize `self.dataArr`. And all the other arrays are also initialized. That's not the problem. Though the rest of your suggestion does solve the immediate issue.

Comment: If it is initialized properly why it does not contain any data after dataArr addObjectFromArray was called?

Comment: Read the first half of my answer for the cause of the issue.

Comment: Means the self.dataArr is not initialized as itself. It only points to another array.

Comment: Which is a perfectly valid form of initialization.

Comment: Ok I change the wording in my answer. Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is.

```
self.dataArr = mutarr0;
```

`self.dataArr` will point to `mutarr0`, `self.dataArr` does not have its own memory. You can see
[this point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VV3Xl.png)

When you remove

```
if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
    [self.dataArr removeAllObjects];
    ...
}
```

`mutarr0` objects is removed , so you should create the memory for `self.dataArr`. Upstairs gave a good resolution.